# Sync contact android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, synchronization, contacts

i am trying to develop an application to sync contact's from device to server

i am aware of GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING, but what i exactly needed is to have my own server for contact's and if i manually added a contact in my server it should be update on device without any interaction by user on device.

The same process in ios and other platformed device's also.
similar to this : [sync Contacts between iPhone(also Android) and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980478/sync-contacts-between-iphonealso-android-and-server)

The core of my question is : how to update any changes made in server on device side automatically
 thank you

Comment: make a vcf of that contact and check with any time new one as a MD5 of that file if any change then download or give notification \

Comment: Yeah i can separate contacts if i had 10 contact's separated to 10 vcf file and updated to server but when i add a contact on my server manually how to update it to server without notification.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into the [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) and trigger the updates via a push notification using GCM. The general structure would be:

- A change is made in the contacts on the server side
- The server sends push notifications to the devices that need to update the information
- The `SyncAdapter` requests the updated data from your server

Comment: Can i achieve this on my ios device also??

Comment: I'm not very familiar with iOS, so I can;t give you an answer on that unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

For IOS you can use [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) just like `GCM` for Android.